# VBA to click a button in a excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

i need to click a button(FormControl) on an excel sheet and run the macro assigned to it, through VBA code.

I tried what was suggested here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130166/clicking-command-button-from-other-workbook 
but it didn't work for me.

Is there any other way to do this ??

Comment: why not? What didn't work? Any errors?

Answer (score 8):

Fairly easy method for doing this, even if it's not really documented.

```
CommandButton1.Value = True
```

Comment: This allowed me to click a button on a Userform where the button's event code was Private.

Answer (score 3):

Did you actually try? Because you want exaclty what is [suggested there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/130325/11683).

```
Application.Run Activesheet.Shapes(1).OnAction
```

Answer (score 0):

If in a worksheet. I used this in the past and it worked!

```
Sheet1.CommandButton1_Click
```

else

```
Sheets("Sheet Name").CommandButton1_Click
```

Comment: Nice, it worked. But in my tests it only works if you remove the Private from the _Click Sub.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to add a button, say on Sheet1, to call the code of CommandButton1 on, say, Sheet2. First I had to delete the 'Private' statement that was in front of CommandButton1_Click(). Then I had to call Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate before calling Worksheets("Sheet2").CommandButton1_Click. Then it worked. You can then add Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate to get you back to your original sheet. So:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet2").CommandButton1_Click
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
End Sub
```