# Adding a command click to excel to search for hello

Tags: vba, excel, highlighting

I'm trying to add a Search command click to my code on Sheet 3. i created a command click and I tried ["Clicking" Command Button from other workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130166/clicking-command-button-from-)
other-workbook but it didn't work. Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong, 
I'm fairly new to vba so any help will be appreciated

```
Sub Sample()
Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
Dim SearchString As String, FoundAt As String
Dim iCount() As String
Dim outws As Worksheet
Dim Sheets As String



Set ws = Worksheets("detail_report")

 Sheets("detail_report").Activate
 ActiveSheet.cmdRefresh_Click

Set oRange = ws.Range("CZ:CZ")

SearchString = "input"

Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
    Set bCell = aCell
    FoundAt = aCell.Address
    Do While ExitLoop = False
        Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
            FoundAt = FoundAt & ", " & aCell.Address
        Else
            ExitLoop = True
        End If
    Loop

     iCount = Split(FoundAt, ", ")

    Set outws = Worksheets("output")

   outws.Range("A2").Value = SearchString

   outws.Range("B2").Value = UBound(iCount) + 1

Else
    MsgBox SearchString & " not Found"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: "...but it didn't work." How doesn't it work? Do you get an error? Does the macro run, but nothing happens? Please describe how it's not working like you expect.

Comment: It runs but nothing happens

Comment: Remove your On Error line, run it and see were it breaks.  Then let us know the line that is highlighted when it stops.

Comment: Your code as posted doesn't compile because the label `Err` is not defined.

Comment: @Scott - where are you seeing the error line? Or did it get edited out?

Comment: @BruceWayne must have gotten edited out.

Answer (score 0):

Your IF conditional is likely not behaving the way you'd like it....
Try a With... End With for speed / clarity.

```
With Worksheets("detail_report").Range("CZ:CZ")
    aCell = .Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False))

    If aCell <> "" Then 'this is probably what you want
        'do your manipulation stuff here
    End if

End With
```