# Invoke Button in Excel Programatically C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have an Excel file with some macro's defined which are invoked on a button click. I can not find which Macro is called on button click. Is there any way I can find that ? How do I invoke button programmatically in C# ?

Comment: `I can not find which Macro is called on button click` - right click the button and see?

Comment: Details about how to add Developer tab to Excel and assigning Macro to buttons, you'll just do the reverse to find out what's currently assigned: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Assign-a-macro-to-a-Form-or-a-Control-button-d58edd7d-cb04-4964-bead-9c72c843a283

Comment: I tried that but its not working.

Comment: Insert option and right click are disabled on button and macros are also password protected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Clicking" Command Button from other workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130166/clicking-command-button-from-other-workbook)

Answer (score 0):

If Insert is disabled on the Developer tab and right-click is disabled on the button, then it sounds like the worksheet or workbook is protected.  And if the VBA Project is password protected then I don't think you'll be able to find out the name of the macro that is called.